# (Python) Keyboard input in the background

Tags: python, keyboard

Can I get an input but when the terminal is in the background? The closest thing I could get was:

```
import keyboard
string = ''
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('h'):
        string += 'h'
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('e'):
        string += 'e'
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('l'):
        string += 'l'
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('o'):
        string += 'o'
    print(string)
```

But with this method I have to manually add all the possible characters, and if I try to execute it and write "hello", I get something like this:

hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhheeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeellllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo

Thank you!

Comment: what exactly do you plan to do with this? create a keylogger? because it can be done in a way easier manner

Comment: Have you tried calling `help("keyboard")` in the Python shell, and looking at the options there?

Comment: input`'h'`
`string == 'h'`
input`'e'`
`string == 'he'`
input`'l'`
`string == 'hel'`

But the output will be:
`h + he + hel = hhehel` However that is not the main problem with your code. In general you're loop should have something like 'key = keyboard.get_key_pressed'. Have you tried a keyboard tutorial?